# Find Smooth Functions from Discrete Datas

Tags: clustering

I'm trying to write a algorithm to solve the following problem, which I did not find any related papers:

Given a set of discrete data points generated by n unknown smooth functions $f_1(x), f_2(x), \cdots, f_n(x)$ at $x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{m}$， how to group these data points into $n$ arrays $a^{(n)}_{i}$ so that the data points in each array come from a single smooth function, i.e.,  $a^{(n)}_{i}=f_{n}(x_i) \forall i$.

For example, if I have a straight line and a quadratic function plotted together in a single figure, I can easily distinguish between these two functions. However, it is very difficult for computer to distinguish these patterns.

This problem seems related to clustering analysis. However, I still didn't find any similar research result about it.

Comment: There isn't any general solution. Even within polynomials, for any $n$ data points, you can find a polynomial passing through the $n$ data points. So without assuming something very strong about the smooth functions, you can't solve this problem

Comment: Some examples of such strong assumptions may be $L$-Lipschitz ($|f(x_i) - f(x_j)| \le L |x_i - x_j|$) or $L$-smooth ($|f'(x_i) - f'(x_j)| \le L |x_i - x_j|$, where you can estimate $f'$ numerically, looking at neighbor points) functions.

Comment: @Dmitry. I think L smooth is a good criterion in my case. I my algorithm, I use an alternative way that require the change of the first derivative to be minimized at each point.